# Global Inheritance with thread classes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance, global

I am wondering how I could use a property of one threaded class as a variable in all other classes (kind of like a global variable), in python. Here is a brief outline.

```
class A(Thread):
      def__init__(self):
           Thread.__init__(self)
           global globalTime
           self.actualTime = gpsd.utc #This gets the real time from a gps module
           globalTime = self.actualTime
           self.classAvar1 = 1
           self.start()
class B(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.classBvar2 = 2
        self.actualTime = globalTime
        self.start()
class C(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.classCvar3 = 3
        self.actualTime = globalTime
        self.start()
```

I am trying to declare `actualTime` in class A and get the time from data read from a gps module. I am then trying to pass this and only this property into classes B and C. Right now I get around it by declaring a global variable called `globalTime`, and setting it equal to the `actualTime` property in class A.

Is this the right approach? Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you use [concurrent.futures.ThreadPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) you can pass it an initializer function which sets some attribute for each thread, sounds like that might be what you want

Comment: Is there a reason not to get the time from the GPS in the calling code and pass it in to the threads? I'd also note that as your question currently stands, multithreading is mostly a red herring. None of the code you show actually runs in the separate threads, the `__init__` methods all run in the parent thread when the thread objects get created. So you can use any method you use with normal classes (e.g. passing an instance of one object to the constructor of another one).